# Cufon breaks on IE7 and IE8 when using <font> in between

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cufon

I encountered this strange phenomena when using cufon text in an html page. IE9, FF, Chrome is working. On IE7 and 8 however the cufon breaks before the font tag. Any ideas how to solve the issue? using  is unfortunately no option since it changes the line-height.

```
<p class="tcblue anyClass">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et CO<font size="-2">2</font>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<font>` tag has been pretty much deprecated for a while. Did you try using a `<sub>`, which is basically what you're looking to achieve.

-EDIT- I just tried your code, using Lato as a font, and it works fine in IE7 and IE8.

-Yet another EDIT- As the original author specified, using `<span style="font-size: 75%">` solved the issue, which is, a better way than using the deprecated `<font>` tag :)

Comment: yeah i tried using `code`<sub>`code` but unfortunately it changes the line height and therefore is no real option :(

Comment: Could you try using a span? `CO<span style="font-size:66%;">2</span>`